# What do rewrite directives do on their own in a location block?

Tags: nginx

As part of a larger nginx config, I have the following:

```
location = /xyz {
    rewrite [^/]$ $scheme://$http_host$uri/ permanent;
}

location ~ /xyz/ {
    rewrite ^(/xyz/)(.*) /$2 last;
}
```

This location block will get requests for **abc.com/xyz**

Now my doubt is that there is no proxy_pass here. So where will Nginx route this request? Also, What is the meaning of these rewrites in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two rules may look similar but they are quite different, [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) has multiple syntaxes.

### First location block - redirect

```
location = /xyz {
    rewrite [^/]$ $scheme://$http_host$uri/ permanent;
}
```

This matches only the path `/xyz` and is rewriting the request to a full url, so it's a redirect.

It is redirecting `/xyz` to the path `/xyz/`. The way it's doing it in the question is not particularly efficient, because:

- `location = /xyz` - match *only* the path `/xyz`
- `rewrite [^/]$` - rewrite if it doesn't end in a `/` - which will always be true
- `$scheme://$http_host$uri/` - this is using the same scheme and host as the request with [$uri](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) as the only meaningful variable - which is going to be the literal string `/xyz` 100% of the time because it's the only path the location block captures
- `permanent` - this just makes it a permanent redirect (http code 301) instead of a temporary redirect (http code 302)

It's equivalent to the following which is probably easier to read and understand:

```
location = /xyz {
    return 301 /xyz/;
}
```

### Second location block - serve files on disk

```
location ~ /xyz/ {
    rewrite ^(/xyz/)(.*) /$2 last;
}
```

This matches any request containing the path `/xyz/` (anywhere as it's a [regular expression match](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)) and rewrites some of them to a different path, where the request will presumably be served as a file located in the path defined by the [root directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).

[That regex](https://regex101.com/r/IcSynA/1) is capturing two groups of text (and the first is the literal string `/xyz/`) and replacing with the second capturing group - but it only works if the string `/xyz/` is at the beginning of the url. For more info about regexes please check existing questions - there are [a lot of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) :)

Here's a few examples of how that regex works:

| Original Request | Serves the file |
| --- | --- |
| /xyz/ | $root/index.html (implied) |
| /xyz/some-folder/ | $root/some-folder/index.html (implied) |
| /xyz/some.file | $root/some.file |
| /xyz/some/other.file | $root/some/other.file |
| /something/xyz/ | $root/something/xyz/index.html (implied) |
| /something/xyz/some.file | $root/something/xyz/some.file |

Those last two are probably a surprise to the author, and a possible exploit.

The likely intent is:

```
location /xyz/ {
    rewrite ^/xyz/(.*) /$1 last;
}
```

Which would only match urls *starting* with `/xyz/`, rewriting to the path without the `/xyz/` prefix.

*Note this only has one capturing group - hence the number in the replacement changed.*

### What's best?

It's not asked directly in the question, but you may be wondering what's the best way to write the config in the question. For each location block I've already given an example but zooming out to look at both together - neither of these location blocks are necessary *with the information in the question*. It very much depends on what the rest of the config looks like but they are equivalent to:

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^/xyz$     /xyz/ permanent; # Ensure trailing / for index requests
    rewrite ^/xyz/(.*) /$1   last;      # Strip /xyz prefix and serve as files-on-disk
}
```

So, no location blocks at all. This is one suggestion how to make things clearer.